set: Illegal option -o pipefail while running make
I'm running FreeBSD 10.4-RELEASE and can't upgrade it at the moment. Previously, 'make' was working fine, but recently I've been getting this error-
$ sudo make install
set: Illegal option -o pipefail
*** Error code 2

Stop.
make[1]: stopped in /data/usr/ports/lang/perl5.24
*** Error code 1

Stop.
make: stopped in /data/usr/ports/lang/perl5.24

$ echo $SHELL
/usr/local/bin/bash


By default make runs a Makefile with /bin/sh, which explains your error.
With GNU make you can change that shell by defining the SHELL variable at the start of the Makefile:
SHELL = /usr/local/bin/bash


Still the same error. Tried both SHELL = /usr/local/bin/bash and SHELL= /usr/local/bin/bash.

OK; then your make command doesn't seem to be GNU; try with gmake

$ gmake Makefile:36: *** missing separator.  Stop.

FreeBSD 10.4 make doesn’t have any way to select the shell; you’re stuck with /bin/sh so you have to clean your Makefile from any bashisms

How to do that if make clean is broken? There are no .o files in the directory.
